# Duplicate javascript inside body tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I'm just curious, what happens if I have two javascript codes, exactly the same in my webpage, one just after the body start tag and another just before the body tag ends, what are the implications?

For context, these are, say, google analytics tracking scripts

Comment: The script will run twice, each time it is loaded into the DOM.

Comment: As @Mash says it will load twice and run twice, but depending on how the script it written the actual results can vary.

Comment: @lemieuxster so it's possible that I get twice the viewing stats? Or does each visit still count as one view? Thanks

Comment: @muyiwamat I can't definitively say since I am unfamiliar with how the Google code works. I imagine they have some kind of safeguard preventing multiple measuring, but that is just my imagination until someone can prove it.

Comment: Google does not deduplicate - every time you send a trackPageview call you'll get a pageview in the GA interface (which is sometimes what you want, for example when you log virtual pageview for ajax calls or something like that).

Comment: If you want more viewing stats, I'm surprised you didn't think of putting the whole script in a `for` loop.

Comment: @Mr Lister, I don't get your point. If the content is changed via ajax it's quite reasonable to track that as a pageview (since that's what a pageview is - looking at new content).